# SQL query TO_INTEGER substr

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Please explain me how to understand the next query

```
TO_INTEGER(substr(NAME,1,length(NAME)-3))*100
```

Comment: The Oracle online documentation is comprehensive.  Please use it to solve simple syntax questions.  For instance, you can read all about SUBSTR() here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm#i87066

Comment: TO_INTEGER is not an Oracle built-in, so you will need to look at the program source to see what it does.  You can find that in the data dictionary view ALL_SOURCE (I'm assuming you're not its owner).

Answer (score 1):

You are taking a substring of NAME ,which happens to be integer in string form and converting it to integer and multiplying it with 100.

Answer (score 1):

For example, NAME is '1234CDE'

The innermost section takes a substring from the input value NAME, starting from position 1 and with a length of equal to the length of the original string minus 3:

```
substr(NAME,1,length(NAME)-3) -- >> '1234'
```

The outer function converts the extracted substring to integer:

```
TO_INTEGER('1234') -- >> 1234 (as integer)
```

Lastly there's a  simple multiplication:

```
1234 * 100 -- >> 123400
```

so

```
TO_INTEGER(substr('1234CDE',1,length('1234CDE')-3)) * 100 -- >> 123400
```

Comment: good answer but steel not understand.. what is doing the substr ? and then length? and the numbers 1 and 3?

Comment: @vili1982 I added some comments to clearify things. What point isn't clear enough so what should I explain further?

Comment: Your answer is wrong on a couple of counts.  Firstly, unlike some other programming languages, an offset of `1` in SUBSTR() is the first position.  So `substr(NAME,1,length(NAME)-3) -- >> 'A123'` .  Also TO_INTEGER is not a built-in Oracle function, also I agree you make a decent guess at what it does,

Comment: Oh and Matten, we're not actually writing code here, so you don't need to write inline comments.  Readability is a feature.

Comment: @APC thank you, I'm not a oracle programmer, but t-sql. I altered the input string to align with your input

Comment: hey APC thank you., cam you provide a better answer and happy new year!